# How to pass component in v-html vuejs nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to show components that are passed through props and output them through v-html. I found a render solution. But I can't figure out how to apply this in a local component, because I'm using nuxt. `Vue.compile(this.vcontent);` give an error

[image]

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: ['vcontent'],
  data() {
    return {
      templateRender: null,
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    if (!this.templateRender) {
      return h('div', 'loading...');
    } else { // If there is a template, I'll show it
      return this.templateRender();
    }
  },
  watch: {

    vcontent:{
        immediate: true, // makes the watcher fire on first render, too.
      handler() {
        var res = Vue.compile(this.vcontent);

        this.templateRender = res.render;
        
        // staticRenderFns belong into $options, 
        // appearantly
        this.$options.staticRenderFns = []
        
        // clean the cache of static elements
        // this is a cache with the results from the staticRenderFns
        this._staticTrees = []
        
        // Fill it with the new staticRenderFns
        for (var i in res.staticRenderFns) {
          //staticRenderFns.push(res.staticRenderFns[i]);
          this.$options.staticRenderFns.push(res.staticRenderFns[i])
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]

if im trying to import Vue in component, webpack gives an error `vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.compile is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
    // if you are using webpack
    build: {
        extend(config, ctx){
            config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common';
        }
    },
    
    // if you are using vite
    vite: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.common'
            }
        },
    }
```

In your component which has component string in content
**my-component.js**

```js
import Btn from '~/components/btn.vue';
export default{
    props: ['vcontent'],
    render(h){
        let self = this;
        return h({
            components: {
                Btn
            },
            template: self.vcontent
        });
    }
}
```

---

2023/06/09 updated:

- [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) for Vue2/Nuxt2
- [vue3-runtime-template](https://github.com/mattelen/vue3-runtime-template) for Vue3/Nuxt3

could be a vanilla and SSR-friendly solution

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Vue compiler is not included, so `Vue.compile` is not defined, but you can enable it in your Nuxt config by aliasing `vue` to the ["full" build](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds):

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
    }
  }
}
```

It also seems the watch handler needs to wait until the [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick-callback) before actually calling `Vue.compile`:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    vcontent: {
      immediate: true,
      async handler() {
        await this.$nextTick()
        const res = Vue.compile(this.vcontent)
        //...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-vue-runtime-compiler?file=nuxt.config.js)